# Avoid reading a data that has not been defined yet (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, null, components, undefined

I'm making an application with The Movie Database and I want to avoid getting an "Undefined" type error on the console.

I understand that I should first check if the object or variable I am trying to access, exists or is defined with an if() check, but the truth is that I don't know how to translate this into code or where I should implement it.

I paste the code for "movieDetails.html" and "movieDetails.ts" so you can get a better idea of ​​what I need.

github.com/Ananekos/App-movies-angular-tmdb_A

Thank you!!

```
<div #moviedetails class="movie-details">

  <section class="header" >
      <app-header [data]="movieDetails"></app-header>
  </section>


  <main id="main">
      <div class="movie-poster-img">
          <div *ngIf="movieDetails.poster_path==null;then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
          <ng-template #thenBlock><img src="assets/images/no-image.png" alt="figure" class="no-image"></ng-template>
          <ng-template #elseBlock><img [attr.src]="highqualityImgUrl+movieDetails.poster_path" alt="{{movieDetails.title}}"></ng-template>
      </div>
  </main>


  <div class="text-center mt-5" *ngIf="movieDetails.logoList!=null">
      <img id="movie-logo" src="{{imgUrl+movieDetails.logoList.file_path}}">
  </div>


  <h1 class="movie-heading mt-5">More About {{movieDetails.title}}</h1>
  <div class="movie-content">
      <table class="details-table">
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Original Name</td>
                  <td  class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.original_title}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Release Date</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.release_date | date}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Status</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.status}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Run Time</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.runtime+" min"}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Rating</td>
                  <td  class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value" > {{'( '+movieDetails.vote_average+' / 10 )'}}
                      <ngb-rating [max]="10" [(rate)]="movieDetails.vote_average" [readonly]="true"></ngb-rating>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Original Language</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">{{movieDetails.original_lan}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="tr-overview">
                  <td class="details-name">OverView</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value movie-description">{{movieDetails.overview}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Production</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">
                      <span *ngFor="let prod of movieDetails.production_companies; let i=index;">
                              <span>{{prod.name}}<span *ngIf='movieDetails.production_companies.length!=i+1'> , </span>
                            </span>
                      </span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td class="details-name">Genres</td>
                  <td class="colon"> | </td>
                  <td class="details-value">
                      <span *ngFor="let genre of movieDetails.genre;let i=index;">
                          {{genre.name}}
                          <span *ngIf='movieDetails.genre.length != i+1'> , </span>
                      </span>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MovieDetails} from 'src/app/core/interface/movie-details';
import myAppConfig from 'src/app/core/config/my-app-config';
import { MoviesService } from 'src/app/services/movies.service';

var movie_id=0;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-details',
  templateUrl: './movie-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-details.component.scss']
})
export class MovieDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  imgUrl:string=myAppConfig.tmdb.imgUrl;
  highqualityImgUrl:string=myAppConfig.tmdb.highQualityImgUrl;

  movieDetails:MovieDetails={} as MovieDetails;

  windowScrolled: boolean=false;

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router,private movieservice:MoviesService,private _sanitizer:DomSanitizer) {
    let id=this.route.snapshot?.params['id'];
    movie_id=id;
    this.movieDetails.crewList=[];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router?.navigateByUrl('/moviedetails/'+movie_id);

    this.getMovieDetails(movie_id);
  }

  getMovieDetails(id:number) {


    let api_url=myAppConfig.tmdb.movieBaseUrl+'/movie/'+id+'?'+myAppConfig.tmdb.apikey;
    this.getMovieDetailsData(api_url);

    
    let backdrop_url=myAppConfig.tmdb.movieBaseUrl+"/movie/"+movie_id+"/images?"+myAppConfig.tmdb.apikey;
    this.getMovieImages(backdrop_url)
  }


  getWatchprovider(watch_provider: string) {
    this.movieservice.getWatchProviders(watch_provider);

    let watch:any;
    this.movieservice.watchData.subscribe((data)=>{
      watch=data;
      this.movieDetails.watchprovider=watch.results.IN[0]?.link;
    })
  }

  getMovieImages(backdrop_url: string) {
    this.movieservice.getAllImages(backdrop_url);

    let tempimagesData:any;
    this.movieservice.movieallImageData.subscribe((data)=>{
        tempimagesData=data;

        if(tempimagesData.backdrops.length=='0'){
          this.movieDetails.background_image=null;
        }
        else{
          this.movieDetails.backdropList=tempimagesData.backdrops;

          this.movieDetails.background_image=this.highqualityImgUrl+tempimagesData.backdrops[0].file_path;
        }

        //Movie Posters Images
          this.movieDetails.posterList=tempimagesData.posters;

        //Movie Logo Images
        if(tempimagesData.logos.length<0){
          this.movieDetails.logoList.file_path=null;
        }else{

          this.movieDetails.logoList=tempimagesData.logos[0];
        }
    })
  }

  getMovieDetailsData(url: string) {
    this.movieservice.getMovieDetails(url);

    let tempMovieDetails:any;
    this.movieservice.moviedetailsData.subscribe((data)=>{

      tempMovieDetails=data;

      //Default Movie Details
      this.movieDetails.title=tempMovieDetails.title;
      this.movieDetails.backdrop_path=tempMovieDetails.backdrop_path;
      this.movieDetails.backdrop_path=tempMovieDetails.backdrop_path;
      this.movieDetails.id=tempMovieDetails.id;
      this.movieDetails.original_lan=tempMovieDetails.original_language;
      this.movieDetails.original_title=tempMovieDetails.original_title;
      this.movieDetails.overview=tempMovieDetails.overview;
      this.movieDetails.popularity=tempMovieDetails.popularity;
      this.movieDetails.poster_path=tempMovieDetails.poster_path;
      this.movieDetails.production_companies=tempMovieDetails.production_companies;
      this.movieDetails.production_countries=tempMovieDetails.production_countries;
      this.movieDetails.runtime=tempMovieDetails.runtime;
      this.movieDetails.genre=tempMovieDetails.genres;
      this.movieDetails.release_date=tempMovieDetails.release_date;
      this.movieDetails.status=tempMovieDetails.status;
      this.movieDetails.vote_average=tempMovieDetails.vote_average;

      if(tempMovieDetails.homepage==""){
        var watch_provider=myAppConfig.tmdb.movieBaseUrl+'/movie/'+movie_id+"/watch/providers?"+myAppConfig.tmdb.apikey;
        this.getWatchprovider(watch_provider);
      }else{
        this.movieDetails.watchprovider=tempMovieDetails.homepage;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I basically need that the console don´t show any errors when you look for films like "DD once upon a dance" which data is mostly unidefined or null.

Comment: It seems that the problem with your code is that you set variable `movie_id` to zero.

Comment: And what I should put instead of 0?